# Want to get the insert statements alone from a file Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file like:

```
insert into table 
values (‘test’,
<xml> 
</xml>);
insert into table 
values (‘test’,
<xml> 
<xml>
<xml>
</xml>);
insert into table 
values (‘test’,
<xml> 
<xml>
<xml>
<xml>
<xml>
</xml>);
```

Now I wish I could read each `insert` (full statements) commands seperately in my program and execute against a table.

How could I do that? Any regex will help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like so?:

```
 String str = "insert into table \n"
            + "values (‘test’,\n"
            + "<xml> \n"
            + "</xml>);\n"
            + "insert into table \n"
            + "values (‘test’,\n"
            + "<xml> \n"
            + "<xml>\n"
            + "<xml>\n"
            + "</xml>);\n"
            + "insert into table \n"
            + "values (‘test’,\n"
            + "<xml> \n"
            + "<xml>\n"
            + "<xml>\n"
            + "<xml>\n"
            + "<xml>\n"
            + "</xml>);";

    String[] commands = str.split(";");
    for(String command : commands)
    {
        System.out.println(command + ";");
    }
```

Yields:

```
insert into table 
values (‘test’,
<xml> 
</xml>);

insert into table 
values (‘test’,
<xml> 
<xml>
<xml>
</xml>);

insert into table 
values (‘test’,
<xml> 
<xml>
<xml>
<xml>
<xml>
</xml>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the contents of the file into a string. Then make use of String.split();

```
 String s = "insert into table values (‘test’,<xml> </xml>); insert into table values             
 ( ‘test’,<xml>" 
 + "<xml><xml></xml>); insert into table values (‘test’,<xml> <xml><xml><xml><xml>    
 </xml>);";
 String[] test = s.split(";");
 for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(test[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are reading the file in one go you could use split on full string input.

If not you could try to have a buffer when you read file, and split when u encounter the query separator and keep doing that till end of file.